# How to Disable previous dates in JQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker, calendar

I started making a JQuery Calendar, which is about choosing an appointment for an event, and I want to disable the dates prior to the current date. I also want to add an #f48024 orange colour to the available dates to make it more clear that they are still available.

I tried it with minDate but it did not work so far.

My question is how could I disable the dates before the current date?

Edit: I added the following code which makes it possible, but it duplicates the calendar, and I don't know why.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#example-popover-2") .datepicker({
    minDate:0,
   })
   }
   )
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}


.popover
{
  left: 5% !important;
  top: 120% !important;
}


.btn 
{
    margin: 1%;
}


#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}


.popover button{
  background: #f48024;
}

.popover button:hover{
  background:#fcb67c;
}

.popover button:focus{
  background: #052049;
}

.popover button:focus:active{
  background: #052049;
}

.arrow {
  
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
  border: 1px solid #dad55e;
  background: #fffa90;
  color: #777620;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
<script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class=" col-md-4">
      <div  class="date-picker-2" placeholder="Recipient's username" id="ttry" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></div>
      <span class="" id="example-popover-2"></span> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-content" class="hidden"> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-title" class="hidden"> </div>


<script>

$('.date-picker-2').popover({
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      return $("#example-popover-2-content").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      return $("#example-popover-2-title").html();
    }

});

$(".date-picker-2").datepicker({

    onSelect: function(dateText) { 
        $('#example-popover-2-title').html('<b>Available Appointments</b>');
        var html = '<button  class="btn btn-success">8:00 am – 9:00 am</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">10:00 am – 12:00 pm</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">12:00 pm – 2:00 pm</button>';
        $('#example-popover-2-content').html('Available times <strong>'+dateText+'</strong><br>'+html);
        $('.date-picker-2').popover('show');
    }
    
});


// I added this part to the code but this duplicates the calendar.
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#example-popover-2") .datepicker({
    minDate:0,
   })
   }
   )

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if there are `minDateTime` and `maxDateTime` available?
Something like:

```
    let minDateTime = new Date(someDateInThePast);
    let maxDateTime = new Date(someDateInTheFuture);
    $(".date-picker-2").datepicker({
        minDateTime: minDateTime,
        maxDateTime: maxDateTime,
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            $('#example-popover-2-title').html('<b>Available Appointments</b>');
            var html = '<button  class="btn btn-success">8:00 am – 9:00 am</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">10:00 am – 12:00 pm</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">12:00 pm – 2:00 pm</button>';
            $('#example-popover-2-content').html('Available times <strong>' + dateText + '</strong><br>' + html);
            $('.date-picker-2').popover('show');
        }

    });
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}


.popover
{
  left: 5% !important;
  top: 120% !important;
}


.btn 
{
    margin: 1%;
}


#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}


.popover button{
  background: #f48024;
}

.popover button:hover{
  background:#fcb67c;
}

.popover button:focus{
  background: #052049;
}

.popover button:focus:active{
  background: #052049;
}

.arrow {
  
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
  border: 1px solid #dad55e;
  background: #fffa90;
  color: #777620;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
<script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class=" col-md-4">
      <div  class="date-picker-2" placeholder="Recipient's username" id="ttry" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"></div>
      <span class="" id="example-popover-2"></span> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-content" class="hidden"> </div>
    <div id="example-popover-2-title" class="hidden"> </div>


<script>

$('.date-picker-2').popover({
    html : true, 
    content: function() {
      return $("#example-popover-2-content").html();
    },
    title: function() {
      return $("#example-popover-2-title").html();
    }

});

$(".date-picker-2").datepicker({
 minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateText) { 
        $('#example-popover-2-title').html('<b>Available Appointments</b>');
        var html = '<button  class="btn btn-success">8:00 am – 9:00 am</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">10:00 am – 12:00 pm</button><br><button  class="btn btn-success">12:00 pm – 2:00 pm</button>';
        $('#example-popover-2-content').html('Available times <strong>'+dateText+'</strong><br>'+html);
        $('.date-picker-2').popover('show');
    }
    
});


</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, I did not find anything like this.

Comment: Check here: https://code.jquery.com/ui/
I am seeing: minDate: null, // The earliest selectable date, or null for no limit
       maxDate: null, // The latest selectable date, or null for no limit
You may also check those examples: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate
Search for minDate

Comment: I edited the snipper to use  minDate: new Date(), which should be the current dateTime.